# In a git post-commit hook how do I get a list of the files that were changed?

Tags: git, githooks

Trying to figure out how long time was spent in a commit in a Git post-commit hook.

I've got a post-commit git hook that submits information over an API about the commit. What I want to do is figure out how long time was spent on the commit. Roughly.

My assumption is that a rough value can be figured out by finding the minimum of all the creation-time and modification-time of the files involved and compare with the maximum creation- and modification-time.

I can easily do this in a Python script. If someone tells me it was the files "foo.txt", "bar.txt" and "path/bla.txt" I can quickly do some arithmetic in a script based on these files.

So, In a git post-commit hook how do I get a list of the files that were changed?

Comment: I forgot to say, I actually know how to get the file names by using `--name-only` but that also includes a bunch of information about the commit which I don't care about.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the modification times on the files have to do with time spent on the commit. The only thing really correlated with that would be the difference between its timestamp and the next-most-recent commit timestamp (which might not be its parent, if you work on several branches).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When writing scripts around git, you should try to stick to the [plumbing commands](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_low_level_commands_plumbing) — their format is less likely to change and easier to parse. Here is a command which outputs the names of the paths which changed in a commit:

```
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id <tree-ish>
```

That aside, you may wish to examine the index, as it contains timestamps about when the files were staged, which might give you an extra edge; however, I don’t believe there is a way to access this information.

Comment: Thanks. Works much better than my git log approach.

Answer (score 1):

Been doing some research and found that `git log --name-only -n1` is the best approach. It's not difficult to get the min. and max. timestamps out of the files by doing a bit of string matching and using the Python `os.stat` module.

As a general solution it still isn't great because the modification times on the files doesn't really reflect the reality of the time spent actually.

Comment: Usually a good idea to wait for some others to answer before you declare that you've found the best approach; jleedev's answer avoids the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [@JoshLee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19750/josh-lee) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206210/5318303).

I tried to complete it:

```
git diff-tree -r --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB --no-commit-id HEAD
```

---

Explanation for `--diff-filter=ACMRTUXB`:

> `ACMRTUXB` includes all changes except `Delete`. See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203