# Link files from different folders so they sync with each other

Tags: git, macos, github, visual-studio-code, synchronization

I have 3 project folders that share some of the source code with each other. Whenever I update these files, I have to go on each of these 3 folders to update the corresponding source code file. This is quite cumbersome, and problematic, as I have to remember which of the files are shared as well.

I tried to hard link these script files (`ln source destination`) on MacOs which worked; whenever I update a linked source code file in one folder, it would automatically update the corresponding files in the other folders. However, what I don't like with this approach is that there is no way to tell what scripts are linked. Using terminal each time I want to introduce shared scripts is not very scalable either.

I use VS Code and recently got introduced to Git/Github. I'm still very novice at both and I'm wondering if they have some features that can solve my problem?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198787/how-to-conveniently-sync-a-file-between-two-git-repositories) is the only similar question I found which I find puzzling. Why aren't more people having this problem or am I searching the wrong terms?

Comment: copy/pasting code accross projects is often the sign that a common library would be useful. What programming language(s) do you use in these projects ?

Comment: Lua. Because it's used in a game engine, the source code can be in different folders. So I don't think a common library would work?