# How to filter git hook post-commit to a specific file?

Tags: githooks

Currently my post-commit githook triggers on committing *all files*. How can I filter the trigger to fire only if **a specific file** e.g. *example.txt* has been commited. I'm currently looking at `git-diff` for file filtering, though believe there could be something more elegant

Comment: You can't. Filtering to decide whether you want to take any action *in the script* is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

[`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) remains the normal approach for that.
See for instance "[In a git post-commit hook how do I get a list of the files that were changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206210/6309)"

```
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id <tree-ish>
```

Once you have the list, you can grep for the file.